# "such the..." or "such as the..."

Tags: such

I found this sentence in a scientific paper I'm editing:

> "...it has been used by applications such the ApplicationA, the ApplicationB, and the ApplicationC."

Is it correct the use of the article "the" directly after "such"?
I searched on the web but I didn't find any mention about the use of "such + the".

Thanks.

Comment: I'm 99+% sure that this is a typo. See my comment below where 'such the' has been used and has been (however correctly)  _intended_ to be used. But the 'so much'  sense and the 'as such the ...' string can't apply here.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)  this odd construction doesn't appear to be a mistake. Furthermore, it seems to be most prevalent in the Academic Register:
[image: Academic Register]
(search string: *[space]* such the *[space]*)

That being said, it *is* quite rare; it may give pause to readers, which is something to consider.

I too am an editor in the scientific realm, and I find that many authors love to use esoteric stuff like this (maybe under the assumption that it adds clout to their opinions somehow). It's hard as an editor to suggest corrections for clarity, especially in this register, so I'd gauge your author's demeanor.

Good luck!

Comment: Does this filter out false positives such as the totally acceptable << as such the evidence was untenable >> or  the type Liberman on [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000284.html) has strong reservations about <<If you'd asked me cold for an unwired judgment, I would have said that "She's such the happy individual" isn't English.>>: << I find that lots of people write things like "I'm such the house wench" / "Poor Homer... such the victim"  / "I am such the good son" / "Wow. You're such the better man" ... / "OMG! Avril is such the coolest!" >>?

Comment: Thanks for your downvote—I'm sorry that you feel my answer is of Ø value at all. It does not filter them out. I gave the search string so that he could see the contextual results himself as the link I first posted to those results wouldn't work. There are instances that match the one he's talking about, and the chart indicates the same proportions of those across registers. Would it make you feel happy if I deleted my answer?

Comment: You need to give **relevant** examples and a measure of how common they are. Ten or twenty would hardly constitute proof that OP's example is acceptable. 'According to the Corpus of Contemporary American English this odd construction doesn't appear to be a mistake' is disingenuous without such data.

Comment: Respectfully, you appear to be living in a prescriptivist dream world. Language is not defined by rules to the same extent Math is; it's a beautiful hodgepodge of everything human—including imperfection and intuition. Sometimes we need to use the imperfect empirical tools to the best of our ability to make judgments about what is currently acceptable or not in certain settings. I don't have time to further explain, but if you cultivate a habit of humbly seeking knowledge to help others rather than fostering a hypercritical demeanor, although it takes more effort it's much more fulfilling. =)

Comment: You seem to be confusing ELU with a website less worried about the correctness and substantiation of answers than many others appear to be. Have you looked at the philosophy behind the site given in the Help Center? And after 'Thanks for your downvote', 'respectfully' is discountable.